# im trying to create 2 seperate arrays (grids) that will reference my html elements give them each index its own ID, A1,A2 and such

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title> Baleship</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bs.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container" class="rows">
        <div id="playerone" class="column" >

          
          <h2><p>PLAYERS BOARD</p></h2>
         <div id="player1Board">
            <div dropzone="true" class="row">
                <div class="box">A1</div>
                <div class="box">A2</div>
                <div class="box">A3</div>
                <div class="box">A4</div>
                <div class="box">A5</div>
                <div class="box">A6</div>
                <div class="box">A7</div>
                <div class="box">A8</div>
                <div class="box">A9</div>
                <div class="box">A10</div>
            </div>
              <div dropzone="true" class="row">
                  <div class="box">B1</div>
                  <div class="box">B2</div>
                  <div class="box">B3</div>
                  <div class="box">B4</div>
                  <div class="box">B5</div>
                  <div class="box">B6</div>
                  <div class="box">B7</div>
                  <div class="box">B8</div>
                  <div class="box">B9</div>
                  <div class="box">B10</div>
                </div>
                <div dropzone="true" class="row">
                  <div class="box">C1</div>
                  <div class="box">C2</div>
                  <div class="box">C3</div>
                  <div class="box">C4</div>
                  <div class="box">C5</div>
                  <div class="box">C6</div>
                  <div class="box">C7</div>
                  <div class="box">C8</div>
                  <div class="box">C9</div>
                  <div class="box">C10</div>
                </div>
                <div dropzone="true" class="row">
                  <div class="box">D1</div>
                  <div class="box">D2</div>
                  <div class="box">D3</div>
                  <div class="box">D4</div>
                  <div class="box">D5</div>
                  <div class="box">D6</div>
                  <div class="box">D7</div>
                  <div class="box">D8</div>
                  <div class="box">D9</div>
                  <div class="box">D10</div>
                </div>
                <div dropzone="true" class="row">
                  <div class="box">E1</div>
                  <div class="box">E2</div>
                  <div class="box">E3</div>
                  <div class="box">E4</div>
                  <div class="box">E5</div>
                  <div class="box">E6</div>
                  <div class="box">E7</div>
                  <div class="box">E8</div>
                  <div class="box">E9</div>
                  <div class="box">E10</div>
                </div>
                <div dropzone="true" class="row">
                  <div class="box">F1</div>
                  <div class="box">F2</div>
                  <div class="box">F3</div>
                  <div class="box">F4</div>
                  <div class="box">F5</div>
                  <div class="box">F6</div>
                  <div class="box">F7</div>
                  <div class="box">F8</div>
                  <div class="box">F9</div>
                  <div class="box">F10</div>
                </div>
                <div dropzone="true" class="row">
                  <div class="box">G1</div>
                  <div class="box">G2</div>
                  <div class="box">G3</div>
                  <div class="box">G4</div>
                  <div class="box">G5</div>
                  <div class="box">G6</div>
                  <div class="box">G7</div>
                  <div class="box">G8</div>
                  <div class="box">G9</div>
                  <div class="box">G10</div>
                </div>
                <div dropzone="true" class="row">
                  <div class="box">H1</div>
                  <div class="box">H2</div>
                  <div class="box">H3</div>
                  <div class="box">H4</div>
                  <div class="box">H5</div>
                  <div class="box">H6</div>
                  <div class="box">H7</div>
                  <div class="box">H8</div>
                  <div class="box">H9</div>
                  <div class="box">H10</div>
                </div>
                <div dropzone="true" class="row">
                  <div class="box">I1</div>
                  <div class="box">I2</div>
                  <div class="box">I3</div>
                  <div class="box">I4</div>
                  <div class="box">I5</div>
                  <div class="box">I6</div>
                  <div class="box">I7</div>
                  <div class="box">I8</div>
                  <div class="box">I9</div>
                  <div class="box">I10</div>
                </div>
                <div dropzone="true" class="row">
                  <div class="box">J1</div>
                  <div class="box">J2</div>
                  <div class="box">J3</div>
                  <div class="box">J4</div>
                  <div class="box">J5</div>
                  <div class="box">J6</div>
                  <div class="box">J7</div>
                  <div class="box">J8</div>
                  <div class="box">J9</div>
                  <div class="box">J10</div>
                </div>
              </div>
        </div>
        
        <div id="two" class="column" ">
          <h2>BATTLESHIP</h2>
          <p id="message">hi</p>
         
            <div id="ships">
                <div id="score" class="text">0</div>
                <div class=""><button class="buttons" id="start">Start</button><button class="buttons" id="rotate">Rotate</button><button class="buttons" id="reset">Reset</button></div>
               
                <div id="shipOne"    class="ship">Battleship<img class="ship" draggable="true" ondrop="updatePlayer1Grid()" id="ship1"  title="battleship" src="/img/battleship2.png"></div>
                <div id="shipTwo"    class="ship">Carrier<img class="ship" draggable="true" ondrop="updatePlayer1Grid()" id="ship2" title="carrier" src="/img/carrier.png"></div>
                <div id="shipThree"   class="ship">Destroyer<img class="ship"  draggable="true" ondrop="updatePlayer1Grid()" id="ship3" title="destroyer" src="/img/destroyer.png"></div>
                <div id="shipFour"   class="ship">Submaraine<img class="ship" draggable="true" ondrop="updatePlayer1Grid()" id="ship4" title="submarine" src="/img/submarine.png"></div>
                <div id="shipFive"    class="ship">Warship<img class="ship" draggable="true" id="ship5" ondrop="updatePlayer1Grid()" title="warship" src="/img/patrol.png"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        
        <div id="three" class="column" >
          <h2> <p id="OPP">OPPONENT'S BOARD</p> </h2>
         
          <div id="computerBoard">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="box">A1</div>
                <div class="box">A2</div>
                <div class="box">A3</div>
                <div class="box">A4</div>
                <div class="box">A5</div>
                <div class="box">A6</div>
                <div class="box">A7</div>
                <div class="box">A8</div>
                <div class="box">A9</div>
                <div class="box">A10</div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                  <div class="box">B1</div>
                  <div class="box">B2</div>
                  <div class="box">B3</div>
                  <div class="box">B4</div>
                  <div class="box">B5</div>
                  <div class="box">B6</div>
                  <div class="box">B7</div>
                  <div class="box">B8</div>
                  <div class="box">B9</div>
                  <div class="box">B10</div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="box">C1</div>
                  <div class="box">C2</div>
                  <div class="box">C3</div>
                  <div class="box">C4</div>
                  <div class="box">C5</div>
                  <div class="box">C6</div>
                  <div class="box">C7</div>
                  <div class="box">C8</div>
                  <div class="box">C9</div>
                  <div class="box">C10</div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="box">D1</div>
                  <div class="box">D2</div>
                  <div class="box">D3</div>
                  <div class="box">D4</div>
                  <div class="box">D5</div>
                  <div class="box">D6</div>
                  <div class="box">D7</div>
                  <div class="box">D8</div>
                  <div class="box">D9</div>
                  <div class="box">D10</div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="box">E1</div>
                  <div class="box">E2</div>
                  <div class="box">E3</div>
                  <div class="box">E4</div>
                  <div class="box">E5</div>
                  <div class="box">E6</div>
                  <div class="box">E7</div>
                  <div class="box">E8</div>
                  <div class="box">E9</div>
                  <div class="box">E10</div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="box">F1</div>
                  <div class="box">F2</div>
                  <div class="box">F3</div>
                  <div class="box">F4</div>
                  <div class="box">F5</div>
                  <div class="box">F6</div>
                  <div class="box">F7</div>
                  <div class="box">F8</div>
                  <div class="box">F9</div>
                  <div class="box">F10</div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="box">G1</div>
                  <div class="box">G2</div>
                  <div class="box">G3</div>
                  <div class="box">G4</div>
                  <div class="box">G5</div>
                  <div class="box">G6</div>
                  <div class="box">G7</div>
                  <div class="box">G8</div>
                  <div class="box">G9</div>
                  <div class="box">G10</div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="box">H1</div>
                  <div class="box">H2</div>
                  <div class="box">H3</div>
                  <div class="box">H4</div>
                  <div class="box">H5</div>
                  <div class="box">H6</div>
                  <div class="box">H7</div>
                  <div class="box">H8</div>
                  <div class="box">H9</div>
                  <div class="box">H10</div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="box">I1</div>
                  <div class="box">I2</div>
                  <div class="box">I3</div>
                  <div class="box">I4</div>
                  <div class="box">I5</div>
                  <div class="box">I6</div>
                  <div class="box">I7</div>
                  <div class="box">I8</div>
                  <div class="box">I9</div>
                  <div class="box">I10</div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="box">J1</div>
                  <div class="box">J2</div>
                  <div class="box">J3</div>
                  <div class="box">J4</div>
                  <div class="box">J5</div>
                  <div class="box">J6</div>
                  <div class="box">J7</div>
                  <div class="box">J8</div>
                  <div class="box">J9</div>
                  <div class="box">J10</div>
                </div>
              </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <script src="/bs.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
.container{
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
}
.column{
  display:inline-block;

}
.row{
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;

}
 


#shipFive{
height: 30%;
width:100%;
text-align: start;
color: navy;
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: bolder;
}
#shipFour{
  height: 30%;
  width:100%;
  text-align: start;
  color: navy;
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: bolder;
}
#shipThree{
  height: 30%;
width:100%;
text-align: start;
color: navy;
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: bolder;
}
#shipTwo{
  height: 30%;
width:100%;
text-align: start;
color: navy;
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: bolder;
}
#shipOne{
  height: 30%;
width:100%;
text-align: start;
color: navy;
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: bolder;
}
#two{
text-align: center;
}
#playerone{
text-align: center;
}
#three{
text-align: center;
}
#ship4{
  height:44px;  
  width:132px;
}
#ship5{
  height:44px;  
  width:88px
}
#ship3{
  height:44px;  
  width:176px
}
#ship2{
  height:44px;  
  width:264px
}
#ship1{
  height:44px;  
  width:220px
}


img{
    height:40%;
    width: 60%;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

.box{
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    border-top: 2px;
    border-left: 2px;
    border-right: 2px;
    border-bottom: 2px;
    border-color: rgb(105, 7, 252); 
    background-color: rgb(45, 45, 122); 
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    color: white;
    border-style: solid;
    border-spacing: 2px;
    row-gap: 2px; 
    justify-content: center; 
}
.box:hover{
    background-color: red;
}
button{
    height: 40px;
    width: 80px;
    color: white;
    background-color:navy;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color:white;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-spacing: 2px;
}
```

```
player1.grid = [
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]];

opponent.grid = [
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]];
```

//so this may sound stupid im not sure, as i have only been coding for 75 days, im trying to //reference my grid with my exsisting html elements, so

```
            <div id="player1Board"
            <div dropzone="true" class="row">
                <div class="box">A1</div>
                <div class="box">A2</div>
                <div class="box">A3</div>
                <div class="box">A4</div>
                <div class="box">A5</div>
                <div class="box">A6</div>
                <div class="box">A7</div>
                <div class="box">A8</div>
                <div class="box">A9</div>
                <div class="box">A10</div>
            </div>
```

/* and so on.... playerBoard[0] references player1.grid[0], so which methods would be best at acheiving this? or am i looking at this issue wrong? could it be acheived via creating some variables or functions, im wanting to have the ability to drag and drop ship on my html element and that location is then expressed in my player1.grid, please be brutally honest my feelings wont be hurt, thanks*/const

```
container = document.getElementById('container');
const playerGridContainer = document.getElementById('playerone');
const dropZone = document.querySelector('dropzone, #playerone,.box');
const computerGridContainer = document.getElementById('three');
const shipsContainer = document.querySelectorAll('.ships');
const draggable = document.querySelectorAll('.draggable');
const rotateBtn = document.querySelector('#rotate');
const startBtn = document.querySelector('#start');
const resetBtn = document.querySelector('#reset');
const square = document.querySelectorAll('.box');
const rows = document.querySelectorAll('.row');
const playerRows = document.querySelector('.playerone, .row');
const computerContainer = document.querySelector('.three');
const computerRows = document.querySelector('.three, .row');
const player1 = {};
const opponent = {};
let allShipsPlaced = false;
const player1GridElement = document.querySelector('#playerone,.box');
console.log(dropZone);
const computerSquares = document.querySelector('#three, .box');
const battleShip = document.getElementById('ship1');
const airCraftCarrier = document.getElementById('ship2');
const destroyer = document.getElementById('ship3');
const submarine = document.getElementById('ship4');
const warShip = document.getElementById('ship5');
const shipsArray = [battleShip, airCraftCarrier, destroyer, submarine, warShip];
battleShip.length = 5;
battleShip.hits = 0;
battleShip.name= 'battleShip';
battleShip.location = [];
airCraftCarrier.length = 6;
airCraftCarrier.name = 'airCraftCarrier';
airCraftCarrier.hits = 0;
airCraftCarrier.location = [];
destroyer.length = 4;
destroyer.name = 'destroyer';
destroyer.hits = 0;
destroyer.location = [];
submarine.name = 'submarine';
submarine.length = 3;
submarine.hits = 0;
submarine.location = [];
warShip.hits = 0;
warShip.name = 'warship';
warShip.length = 2;
warShip.location = [];
opponent.shipsArray = [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1,], [1, 1]];
console.log(battleShip);
boxOccupiedShipLocationsArray = [];
let hoverArray = [];
let grid = player1.grid;
let dragLeaveArray = [];
let dragEnterArray = [];
let dropArray = [];
let draggableArray = [];
var array = [];

array.push(square);

console.log(array)




function createGrid(columnCount, rowCount) {
    const player1Board =document.createElement('div');
    player1Board.className = 'grid';
    player1Board.id = 'player1GridEl';
player1Board.innerHTML = player1.grid;

    const grid = [];
    for (let x = 0; x < columnCount; x++) {
      grid[x] = []; // set up inner array
      for (let y = 0; y < rowCount; y++) {
         addCell(grid, x, y);
         console.log(grid);
      }
    }
    return grid;
  }
 
  function addCell(grid, x, y) {
;     grid[x][y] = cell(); // create a new object on x and y
  }
  function cell(x,y) {
    x = [];
    y = [];
    return {};
        
}
 
  const grids = createGrid(10, 10);
  function one(){
    console.log(player1.grid);
};one();

  let DataArray = [];
  player1GridElement.addEventListener("drop", (event) => {
    // prevent default action (open as link for some elements)
    event.preventDefault();
    // move dragged element to the selected drop target
    if (event.target.className === "dropzone") {
      dragged.parentNode.removeChild(dragged);
      event.target.appendChild(dragged);
    }
  });
  player1GridElement.ondrop=function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var data = e.dataTransfer.getData("text");
      DataArray.push(data);
      
      console.log(typeof player1.grid)
      console.log('DRIP DROP');
      console.log(e.target.id);
      console.log(DataArray)

  };
rotateBtn.onclick=function(){
          console.log('rotated')
};
resetBtn.onclick=function(){
    console.log('reset')
};
battleShip.onclick=function(){
    console.log('battleship clicked');
    console.log(battleShip.length);
};
 battleShip.ondragend=function(e){
  
    console.log(player1GridElement);
   
    console.log(battleShip.location);
    console.log(typeof player1.grid);

};
warship.ondragend=function(event){
    console.log('warShip.dragend');
};
warship.onclick=function(){
    console.log('warship clicked')
};
submarine.ondragend=function(event){
    console.log('Submarine.dragend');
};
submarine.onclick=function(){
    console.log('submarine clicked')
};
airCraftCarrier.ondragend=function(e, ACArray){
    ACArray = [1,1,1,1,1,1];
    ACArray.join(player1.grid[e.target]);
   console.log(this.nodeType);
    console.log('airCraftCarrier.dragend');
    player1.grid.concat(ACArray);
    console.log(player1.grid);


console.log(ACArray);
    console.log(player1.grid);
};
airCraftCarrier.onclick=function(){
    console.log('aircraftcarrier clicked')
};
destroyer.ondragend=function(event){
    console.log('Destroyer.dragend');
};
destroyer.onclick=function(){
    console.log('destroyer clicked')
};

function placeShip(ship, x, y, orientation) {
    
    if (orientation === 'horizontal') {
        for (let i = 0; i < ship.size; i++) {
            player1.grid[x] [y + i] = ship instanceof battleship;
        }           
    } else {               
        for (let i = 0; i < ship.size; i++) {                   
            player1.grid[x + i] [y] = ship instanceof battleship;               
        }           
    }       
};


shipsContainer.forEach(ship => ship.addEventListener('dragstart', dragStart))
square.forEach(square => square.addEventListener('dragstart', dragStart))
square.forEach(square =>square.addEventListener('dragover', dragOver))
square.forEach(square => square.addEventListener('dragenter', dragEnter))
square.forEach(square => square.addEventListener('dragleave', dragLeave))
square.forEach(square => square.addEventListener('drop', dragDrop))
square.forEach(square => square.addEventListener('dragend', dragEnd))

square.dragOver=function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('dragover')
};

let selectedShipNameWithIndex
let draggedShip
let draggedShipLength
let airCraftCarrierLocation;
let battleShipLocation;
let submarineLocation;
let warShipLocation;
let destroyerLocation;

shipsContainer.forEach(ship => ship.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  console.log('draggable');
   console.log('e listener')
}))
let DArray = [];
function dragStart(){
   
    console.log('dragstart');
   
}


function dragOver(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  console.log('dragOver event');
      hoverArray.push(e.target.id);
      console.log(hoverArray)    
  };
function dragEnter(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  dragEnterArray.push(e.target.id);
  console.log(dragEnterArray);
  console.log('dragEnter event');
}

function dragLeave(e) {
   dragLeaveArray.push(e.target);
   console.log(dragLeaveArray);
    console.log('dragleave event');
     
      };

function dragDrop(e) {
    e.target.classList.add('occupied');
   e.target = player1.grid[e.target]
    boxOccupiedShipLocationsArray.push(e.target.textContent)
    shipsPlacedArray.push(1);
    dropArray.push(e.target.textContent);
    console.log(dropArray);
    console.log(boxOccupiedShipLocationsArray);
    console.log('dropped Event');
    console.log(shipsPlacedArray);
   
};

function dragEnd() {
        console.log('dragEnd event');
};



player1GridElement.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    console.log('clicked')
});
computerSquares.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    console.log('clicked')
});



function shipLocation(){
 
}

player1.shipsArray = [
    { name:'battleShip', size: 5, hits: 0, location: [] } ,
    { name:'airCraftCarrier', size: 6, hits: 0, location: [] },
    { name:'destroyer', size: 4, hits: 0, location: [] } ,
    { name:'submarine', size: 3, hits: 0, location: [] } ,
    { name:'warShip', size: 2, hits: 0, location: [] } ];

    

opponent.shipsArray = [
    { ship1: { size: 5, hits: 0, location: [] } },
    { ship2: { size: 6, hits: 0, location: [] } },
    { ship3: { size: 4, hits: 0, location: [] } },
    { ship4: { size: 3, hits: 0, location: [] } },
    { ship5: { size: 2, hits: 0, location: [] } }];
   let  shipsPlacedArray = [];

    function updatePlayer1Grid(e){
        player1.shipsArray[0] = battleShip;
        player1.shipsArray[1] = airCraftCarrier;
        player1.shipsArray[2] = destroyer;
        player1.shipsArray[3] = submarine;
        player1.shipsArray[4] = warShip;
        player1.shipsArray[0].location = battleShipLocation;
        player1.shipsArray[1].location = airCraftCarrierLocation;
        player1.shipsArray[2].location = destroyerLocation;
        player1.shipsArray[3].location = submarineLocation;
        player1.shipsArray[4].location = warShipLocation;
        };
    function updateComputerGrid(e){};

square.forEach(function (square) {
    square.addEventListener('onDrop', onDrop => {
        if (e.target.classList.contains('hover')) {
            e.target.classList.remove('hover');
            console.log('droppedITBABY');
        }
    });
});

player1.grid = [
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]];

opponent.grid = [
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],

    startBtn.addEventListener('click', function play() {
        plays();
        console.log('play fn');


    });

             
    
    shipPlaced = false;


function plays() {
    alert("This is an alert dialog box");
    if (allShipsPlaced = false) {
        alert("You must place all your ships before you can start the game");
        player1.placeShips();
    } else {
        alert("Game has started")

    }
};

console.log(player1.grid[0])

 function board(){
    var board = [];
    
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        board[i] = [];
        for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            board[i][j] = 0
            console.log(board[i][j])
        }
        console.log( board );
    }
    return board;
} board()

let row = document.querySelectorAll('.row');
col =10;
     for(row in board); 
     console.log(board[row]); 
     for(col in board); 
     console.log(board[col]); 
     
     
   let elements = document.querySelector('#player1Board');
   console.log(elements)
         
   for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < elements[i].length; j++) {
      elements[i][j] = player1.grid;
     // for (let k = 0; k < elements[i][j].length; k++){
        
    console.log(elements[i][j]);
    }};
    for(player in player1Board){
    console.log(player1.grid);
    console.log(player1.grid);
    console.log(player1Board.innerHTML);
    }
    
  
 
    console.log(dragEnterArray);
```

Comment: Your question in unclear.... have you tried something?

Comment: As far as i've understood your question, I think your approach is right. The thing I am concerned here is that you have used ondrop() on the img itself. ondrop() event is used on the target on which the draggable item is dropped on.

reference: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_ondrop.asp

Comment: im trying to create 2 seperate arrays (grids) that will reference my html elements give them each index its own ID, A1,A2 and so  playerBoard[0] references player1.grid[0],

Comment: so ive put all the code i have in my file up; so this is mostly my attemps at creating retreivable data so i can learn as i go, all the excess arrays and  grids are my attempt to  make player1.grid wich is10 arrays of ten elements in each array, a (grid), can i create a function that will allow my player1.grid to update when i drop a ship on the html elements that ive already created

Comment: @AnasMohammadSheikh thanks ive made the appropriate edits as ive explained to the gentleman above this comment it seems im may not be grasping a concept and if you have the time or interest in giving me a few pointers or critisism i would be especially greatfull if not i understand 100%

Answer (score 0):

divs such as “A2” have not been given an id. You have just created content in the div.

Try `<div class="box" id=“A2”>A2</div>` . Alternatively just declare a table and within each td element an id like `<td id=“pbA2”> or <td id=“cbA2”>` .

Alternatively there are the CSS selectors like nth child you could use to select the elements.

Of course, if you are generating battleship moves on a server just write out the board on each iteration from the server.

Comment: so ive put all the code i have in my file up; so this is mostly my attemps at creating retreivable data so i can learn as i go, all the excess arrays and grids are my attempt to make player1.grid wich is10 arrays of ten elements in each array, a (grid), can i create a function that will allow my player1.grid to update when i drop a ship on the html elements that ive already created

Comment: thanks ive made the appropriate edits as ive explained to the gentleman above this comment it seems im may not be grasping a concept and if you have the time or interest in giving me a few pointers or critisism i would be especially greatfull if not i understand 100%